# Does It make sense to interprete variables with low accuracy but high R squared in Random Forest?

Tags: random-forest, goodness-of-fit, accuracy

I did random forest analysis and I obtained two graphs. In the first one (left hand side) we can see the measure of importance of each predictor and on the second one (right hand side) is the proportion of variance explained by each predictor in random forest.

I am not sure about the interpretation of some predictors. For instance, the predictor ***forest cover*** has negative value for accuracy importance (indicating the predictor explains little or nothing), but the proportion of variance explained ($R^2$) is the highest for that predictor.

Does it make sense to interpret variables with high $R^2$ values even if the accuracy of those predictors are zero (or negative)?

[image]

Comment: Relevant threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52482/variable-importance-randomforest-negative-values & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918320/what-does-negative-incmse-in-randomforest-package-mean

Comment: Hey mkt, thank you! I understood that the variable with zero or negative values does not have a role in the prediction,i.e, not important (That is what the first graph shows). But, this means that I can't consider these variables even they are responsible of big proportion of variance explained (Second graph)?

Comment: Interesting, I am familiar with the feature accuracy & Gini impurity methods of quantifying importance, but not this R2 weighted importance metric. If you can point me towards more info on that (such as via the package & function you are using), I might be able to help.

Comment: I'm assuming you have ruled out obvious problems such as those caused by using very few trees in your forest.

Comment: Not really, i choose 10000 trees! I am using the gradientForest package, the function that I used was: gf <- gradientForest(data= cbind(envir, comm), 
      predictor.vars = colnames (envir), response.vars= colnames(comm), 
      ntree = 10000, transform = NULL, compact = F,nbin = F,
      maxLevel = 5, corr.threshold = 0.5).

Comment: The vignette (http://gradientforest.r-forge.r-project.org/biodiversity-survey.pdf) adds a little clarity: the metric is the mean importance *weighted by species R2*. However, I fail to see how a negative R2 would become positive based on weighting alone. Are both metrics calculated the same way i.e. by conditional permutation? If not, that might explain the discrepancy. (FYI, posting more information about how you achieved this result will help us understand it better and possibly diagnose it).

Comment: Hi mkt, thank you again. The R^2 weighted importance is the weighted average accuracy importance after setting negative accuracy importances to zero, where the weighting is the cross-validated OOB R^2 per forest (species). Because of the truncation to zero, these measures are non-negative. Moreover, I found that the most reliable importances are the eqn{R^2} weighted importances. The authors do hint in the help doc pages which measures to use.