# Random Forest: Variable Importance plot depicing negative increase (decrease) in MSE

Tags: random-forest, mse, importance

I'm using a RF analysis to evaluate 75ish predictor variables pertaining to my response variable of percent functional area across some wetland sites. I selected the default ntree value of 500, and my mtry value is roughly p/3 (25), although my model performs slightly better with an mtry value of 15. My sample size is small (n = 556). When I print my variable importance plot (shown here), several variables are depicted as having a negative increase in MSE (aka a decrease in MSE) when they are permuted. [image: Variable Importance Plot with variables that decrease MSE when permuted]

This implies that when the values for this variable are randomly shuffled, it somehow makes the model more accurate. However, when I remove these variables, the % of variance explained by my model decreases slightly and the mean of squared residuals increases, implying that removing these variables makes my model *less* accurate.

I've tried changing my mtry and ntree (including using TuneRF to find the best mtry and plotting OOB error against ntree to find the best ntree value), but my VIMP plot still ends up depicting variables that decrease MSE. It's worth noting that nearly all of these problematic variables pertain to monthly sums or the number of days of precipitation. I've tried removing them 1 at a time in case there are any monthly precip variables that *are* useful to the model, which is tedious because every time I remove one "bad" variable, another takes its place. If I just remove all of them, the VIMP plot looks better and there's only 1 variable that is "acting weird" by having a decrease in MSE (shown here), but my % variance explained drops from 77 to 70% and my mean of squared residuals increases from ~78 to 108. [image: Variable importance plot when all precipitation variables are removed]

Is this because my sample size is so small? Should I just exclude all of these variables, or leave them in since removing them decreases my % var explained and increases the mean of squared residuals?

Comment: Have you done any exploratory data analysis to plot the outcome against the "bad" variables and read this [explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/284859/237901) about how *randomForest::importance* estimates feature importances? There are also alternative methods such as [Boruta](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boruta/index.html).

Comment: I had not read this, it aligns with my understanding and it was helpful to read step 3. I've created partial dependence plots for the "Bad" variables (haven't plotted them against the outcome directly though), the partial dependence plots depicted very little marginal effect of the predictor on the response variable, which does further demonstrate they are not impactful. Thank you for the suggestion of Boruta.

Comment: If all of your other predictors are highly correlated, adding random features that have low feature importance could make your random forest model more accurate because it can decrease the correlation within trees. If you want to make the best possible model, try recursive feature elimination or recursive feature selection. If you want to know the scientific importance of your features look up marginal feature importance methods.